# Implementing BFS on a graph

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I have vertices in graph which represent towns. I am trying to find a shortest path from point A to point B.

I have created a graph class.

```
struct Edge{
    string name;
    vector< Edge *> v;
    Edge( string n ){
        name = n;
    }
};

class Graph{
public:
        Graph(){};
        void addEdge( string start_point , string end_point){
            graph[ start_point ] -> v.push_back( graph[ end_point ]);
        }
        void addPeak( string name ){
            graph[name] = new Edge(name);
            size++;
        }
        void printPeaks(){
            for( auto &a : graph){
                cout << a . first << endl;
            }
        }
    void getRoad( string starting , string ending ){
        map< string , bool > visited;
        queue< Edge * > q;

        for( auto &a : graph ){
            visited[ a.first ] = false;
        }

        q.push( graph[starting] );
        while( ! q.empty( )){
                Edge *tmp = q.front();
                q.pop();
                cout << tmp -> name << endl;
                if( tmp -> name  == ending ){
                        cout << "found " << endl;
                        break;
                }
                for( unsigned int i = 0; i < tmp -> v.size() ; i++){
                    q.push( tmp -> v [i]);
                }

        }
    }
private:
    map< string , Edge *> graph;
    int size = 0;
};
```

I am adding vertices and edges as follows.

```
Graph g;
    g.addPeak("Prague");
    g.addPeak("Bratislava");
    g.addPeak("Budapest");
    g.addPeak("Berlin");
    g.addPeak("Moscow");
    g.addPeak("London");
    g.addEdge("Bratislava", "Berlin");
    g.addEdge("Bratislava" , "Budapest");
    g.addEdge("Bratislava" , "London");
    g.addEdge("Berlin" , "Moscow");
    g.addEdge("Budapest" , "Berlin");
    g.getRoad("Bratislava", "Moscow");
```

On the last line I want to find the shortest path from Bratislava to Moscow.
As i demonstrated in code, I can find the path, but meanwhile all others town that have edge with Bratislava are also printed. Instead of the desired output

```
Bratislava 
Berlin
Moscow
```

it prints the following list.

```
Bratislava
Berlin
Budapest
London
Moscow
```

How can i store and print the path just the path i want?

Comment: Remember the predecessor of every node and follow these links back when you find the target.

Answer (score 0):

Without giving the explicit imlementational details, this can be done as follows.

1. You could use a user-defined stack to explicitly store cities which are currently visited. When the target city is reached, the stack contains the path to the city.
2. Your implementation does not use a separate type to represent the nodes. There is nothing wrong with that. However, if it would use a separate type, the type could be endowed with a parent reference to another node. If an edge is followed by the algorithm, the parent reference of the visited node would be set to the node from which the visit is initiated. In that way, on reaching the target node, the desired path could be generated by following these references.
3. As the implementation lacks the separate type for nodes, an auxiliary dictionary (which uses the city names as both keys and values, where the value is the parent city). On reaching the destination node, the desired path could be generated by iteratively following to the parent in the dictionary. This approach would use the same idea as in point 2 without the introduction of a new type for the nodes.

Comment: What do you mean by separate type to represent the nodes?

Comment: In the current implementation the nodes are represented implicitly by city names, which are of a string type. Currently there is not possiblity to add additional properties to that type.